# inserting data to a grakn schema

Tags: python, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql, knowledge-graph

I have created the below grakn schema

```
define  
contract sub relation,     
  relates manufacturer,     
  relates product;  
drug sub entity,    
  plays product,    
  has product_name,    
  has code;  
company sub entity,    
  plays manufacturer,    
  has manufacturer_name;
      
product_name sub attribute,  
  datatype string;  
manufacturer_name sub attribute,  
  datatype string;  
code sub attribute,  
  datatype string;
```

I have 3 csv (drug, company and contract)

1. drug has product_name (unique) and code
2. company has manufacturer_name (unique)
3. contract has product_name and manufacturer_name (unique combining both)

I am using the same migrate.py provided by grakn [modifying the names of the tables]. During ingestion the below error pops up.

<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "GraqlSemanticException-name doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'. Please check server logs for the stack trace."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1588172437.178000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:48555","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"GraqlSemanticException-name doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'. Please check server logs for the stack trace.","grpc_status":3}"
>

In the phone_calls example provided by grakn I see ID being generated (is it generated automatically?)
I need to insert data into the fields (company, contracts and drug). If required I can share the migrate.py which i have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the names used in your migrate.py and csv files. Both should be same to insert the data into grakn-DB. Example:
If your query is like:

```
'insert $company isa company, has name "' + company["name"] + '";'
```

So in your csv file the header should be "name".
Hope this helps.